# Hiding Settings Area based on security role in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to hide the "Settings" area in CRM 2011 such that it is visible only to users 
having a certain security role.
I have followed the suggestions mentioned in the following posts

https://community.dynamics.com/product/crm/f/117/t/28176.aspx

http://taoofcrm.com/2011/06/09/hiding-areas-in-the-sitemap/

and have created a custom entity as indicated in the posts. 
None of my other security roles have "Read" on this entity. "System Customizer" by
default has "Read" on this entity.

I then included a Privilege tag like so
<Privilege Entity="Your custom entity name here" Privilege="Read" />
in each and every SubArea of Each <Group> that is defined for the "Settings" Area 
under the <SiteMap> node and uploaded the solution containing this customization back to my org.

After importing the solution, I'm noticing that if I click on Settings --> Administration 
the progress bar at the bottom of the browser stays busy for a long time and 
I have also noticed an "Error on Page" message on the bottom left of the page. 
Cicking on "Security Roles" or "Users" does the same thing.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Posting details of that error message would be a good start ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately there are no error details. I would have posted them otherwise

Comment: It's common to miss the content of such error messages due to default settings in Internet Explorer. Recommend that during development you set IE settings as follows to ensure that you see all exceptions and errors: Tools > Internet Options > Advanced > Browsing: `Disable Script Debugging (Internet Explorer)` [unticked], `Disable Script Debugging (Other)` [unticked], `Display a notification about every script error` [ticked]. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I'll take a stab in the dark. I suspect you've messed up the SiteMap customisation. Roll back your changes and then go and install Tanguy's excellent [SiteMap Editor tool from here](http://mscrmtools.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/new-tool-sitemap-editor-for-microsoft.html). Do the same things you tried to do by hand and see if it works this time.

Comment: I verified that the XML was well formed but I was doing the upload of unmanaged solution after making changes to the customziation file. not sure if I was doing that correctly. I used the site map editor and directly edited the sitemap for the organization and uploaded it. No errors encountered.